# UWP, creating local file to store data

Tags: file, parsing, uwp, local

I just need codes that brings data from basic text file. I will get data for login and password textbox. There will be checkbox for "remember".

If user checks it, app should store those "username" and "pass" information into file so app can bring them later. Is it possible?

I can gather data from a file but I can't write something into a file.

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=uwp+how+to+write+text+to+file

Comment: You should not save user credentials in plain text! use
 `Credential Locker` instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker

Comment: I tried what is written in here :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files
 but somehow it didnt work. I couldnt find the text that it "saves"

Comment: @HesamKashefi thank you so much, It's working very well ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem with `Credential Locker`. Many thansk to @HesamKashefi,[UWP, creating local file to store data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343878/uwp-creating-local-file-to-store-data?noredirect=1#comment85691582_49343878)

Here is the solution:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker